# Is the completion of a measure space necessary?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Most important theorems in measure theory do not assume the completeness of measure spaces.
Monotone convergence theorem, Dominated convergence theorem, and Fubini's theorem, to name a few.
So I wonder if the completion of a measure space is necessary.
In particular do we need to consider Lebesgue measurable sets which are not Borel sets?

Comment: "Need" is a strong word. We need food and water, and maybe some sleep. Beyond the computational aspect, none of math is needed. Someone else will hopefully give a more helpful answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why complete measure spaces?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188972/why-complete-measure-spaces)

Comment: At least there's an issue with DCT. The a.e. converging point $f$ may not be measurable if the underlying measure space is not complete --- see http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Dominated_convergence_theorem.